# Python Django Shell - Three dots

Tags: python, django, shell

Just running through [Django Tutorial 4](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04.html) and I am wondering if anyone can tell me if there is a name for the three dots `...` that appear in the shell after one opens a class and how to get back to the normal `>>>` correctly?

This shell is accessed by `python manage.py shell`

```
>>> class SilentAssertionError(AssertionError):
...     silent_variable_failure = True
>>> class PersonClass4:
...     def first_name(self):
...         raise SilentAssertionError
>>> p = PersonClass4()
>>> t.render(Context({"person": p}))
u'My name is .'
```

E.G. After getting to the end of the line

```
...         raise SilentAssertionError
```

When I press return I still have `...` at the prompt. If I type the next line in here I get an error. What I have been doing so far is to hit return twice to get it back to the normal `>>>`

Also is there a name for the `>>>` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `>>>` and `...` are called prompts. They are shown by the console to tell you that it is expecting you to type something.

In the particular case of the Python console, `>>>` tells you to start typing a new statement, and `...` means that you haven't finished it yet so you know that you need to complete your statement.

The `...` after `raise SilentAssertionError` is shown because the interpreter doesn't know whether you want to add more stuff to the `first_name` method or to the `PersonClass4` class. By entering an empty line, you signal that you're done.